# Minecraft doesn't connect to Mojang servers/the internet (15.04)

Tags: java, 15.04, minecraft, openjdk, oracle

I've been trying to run Minecraft on Ubuntu 15.04 for a while. Whenever I try running, it won't download the launcher pack and it gives me this message:

```
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is Jun 19, 2015 2:34:53 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '3.19.0-20-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_45'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 2/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 3/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 4/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 5/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 6/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 7/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 8/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 9/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 10/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to download while being forced
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:95)
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)


Please fix the error and restart.
```

(I don't know how or if it's possible to make spoilers)

I've downloaded the launcher.pack manually, so it goes into the launcher and shows me the login screen, but then it says it can't access Mojang servers, and I can't get past that. I found someone else with the same problem, and s/he said that his/her problem was solved when s/he switched from OpenJDK (I *was* using OpenJDK) to Oracle Java (Or at least I tried.) I did that, but nothing changed. This is what happens when I use `java -version`

```
*****@Desktop-Ubuntu:~/Software/Minecraft$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.9.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.9.0-ea-b66)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.9.0-ea-b66, mixed mode)
```

Comment: this is related to truststore: see the related q&a  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378235/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-java-security-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-th for an explanation

Comment: This should not be marked as already having an answer. These are two different problems with two different solutions. None of the solutions on that problem answer this question. And besides, that other one has the most overcomplicated 'solution' ever as the first one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`